Radio Image Labels Overflow Grid
New to CSS and can't figure out how to dynamically change the heights of the thumbnails so they don't overflow the cyan container.

The HTML code is for the largest grid size with 25 items. Every other category has less.


.course-container {
    display: grid;
    max-height: 5fr;
    width: 5fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5,1fr);
    background-color: cyan;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.5%;
    grid-gap: 3%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.course-container > div img {
    display: block;
    max-width: calc(100% - 10px);
    max-height: 1fr;
    opacity: 80%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;

    &:hover {
        opacity: 100%;
        transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
    }
}
.course-container input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
    border: 5px solid salmon;
    background-color: salmon;
    opacity: 100%;
    mask-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 4%, gold 0),
                linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 4%, gold 0);
    mask-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    mask-size: 51% 51%;
}
   <div class="course-container">
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Animal-Crossing" value="Animal Crossing"/>
                        <label for="Animal-Crossing">
                            <img src="images/courses/Animal-Crossing.png" alt='Animal Crossing'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Big-Blue" value="Big Blue"/>
                        <label for="Big-Blue">
                            <img src="images/courses/Big-Blue.png" alt='Big Blue'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Bone-Dry-Dunes" value="Bone-Dry Dunes"/>
                        <label for="Bone-Dry-Dunes">
                            <img src="images/courses/Bone-Dry-Dunes.png" alt='Bone-Dry Dunes'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Bowsers-Castle" value="Bowser's Castle"/>
                        <label for="Bowsers-Castle">
                            <img src="images/courses/Bowsers-Castle.png" alt='Bowsers Castle'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Cloudtop-Cruise" value="Cloudtop Cruise"/>
                        <label for="Cloudtop-Cruise">
                            <img src="images/courses/Cloudtop-Cruise.png" alt='Cloudtop Cruise'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Dolphin-Shoals" value="Dolphin Shoals"/>
                        <label for="Dolphin-Shoals">
                            <img src="images/courses/Dolphin-Shoals.png" alt='Dolphin Shoals'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Dragon-Driftway" value="Dragon Driftway"/>
                        <label for="Dragon-Driftway">
                            <img src="images/courses/Dragon-Driftway.png" alt='Dragon Driftway'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Electrodome" value="Electrodome"/>
                        <label for="Electrodome">
                            <img src="images/courses/Electrodome.png" alt='Electrodome'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Excitebike-Arena" value="Excitebike Arena"/>
                        <label for="Excitebike-Arena">
                            <img src="images/courses/Excitebike-Arena.png" alt='Excitebike Arena'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Hyrule-Circuit" value="Hyrule Circuit"/>
                        <label for="Hyrule-Circuit">
                            <img src="images/courses/Hyrule-Circuit.png" alt='Hyrule Circuit'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Ice-Ice-Outpost" value="Ice Ice Outpost"/>
                        <label for="Ice-Ice-Outpost">
                            <img src="images/courses/Ice-Ice-Outpost.png" alt='Ice Ice Outpost'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Mario-Circuit-MK8.png" value="Mario Circuit - MK8"/>
                        <label for="Mario-Circuit-MK8.png">
                            <img src="images/courses/Mario-Circuit-MK8.png" alt='Mario Circuit - MK8'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Mario-Kart-Stadium" value="Mario Kart Stadium"/>
                        <label for="Mario-Kart-Stadium">
                            <img src="images/courses/Mario-Kart-Stadium.png" alt='Mario Kart Stadium'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Mount-Wario" value="Mount Wario"/>
                        <label for="Mount-Wario">
                            <img src="images/courses/Mount-Wario.png" alt='Mount Wario'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Mute-City" value="Mute City"/>
                        <label for="Mute-City">
                            <img src="images/courses/Mute-City.png" alt='Mute City'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Rainbow-Road-MK8" value="Rainbow Road - MK8"/>
                        <label for="Rainbow-Road-MK8">
                            <img src="images/courses/Rainbow-Road-MK8.png" alt='Rainbow Road - MK8'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Shy-Guy-Falls" value="Shy Guy Falls"/>
                        <label for="Shy-Guy-Falls">
                            <img src="images/courses/Shy-Guy-Falls.png" alt='Shy Guy Falls'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Sunshine-Airport" value="Sunshine Airport"/>
                        <label for="Sunshine-Airport">
                            <img src="images/courses/Sunshine-Airport.png" alt='Sunshine Airport'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Super-Bell-Subway" value="Super Bell Subway"/>
                        <label for="Super-Bell-Subway">
                            <img src="images/courses/Super-Bell-Subway.png" alt='Super Bell Subway'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Sweet-Sweet-Canyon" value="Sweet Sweet Canyon"/>
                        <label for="Sweet-Sweet-Canyon">
                            <img src="images/courses/Sweet-Sweet-Canyon.png" alt='Sweet Sweet Canyon'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Thwomp-Ruins" value="Thwomp Ruins"/>
                        <label for="Thwomp-Ruins">
                            <img src="images/courses/Thwomp-Ruins.png" alt='Thwomp Ruins'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Toad-Harbor" value="Toad Harbor"/>
                        <label for="Toad-Harbor">
                            <img src="images/courses/Toad-Harbor.png" alt='Toad Harbor'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Twisted-Mansion" value="Twisted Mansion"/>
                        <label for="Twisted-Mansion">
                            <img src="images/courses/Twisted-Mansion.png" alt='Twisted Mansion'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Water-Park" value="Water Park"/>
                        <label for="Water-Park">
                            <img src="images/courses/Water-Park.png" alt='Water Park'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="course-thumbnail mk8Courses">
                        <input type="radio" name="course-thumbnail" id="Wild-Woods" value="Wild Woods"/>
                        <label for="Wild-Woods">
                            <img src="images/courses/Wild-Woods.png" alt='Wild Woods'>
                        </label>
                    </div>
</div>



Here is a link to the GitHub Respository in case you wanted to examine the full code.

Can you add the html code?

Absolutely, just added the HTML.

You need to change in: .course-container
From: grid-gap: 3%;
to: grid-gap: 3vw;
Using vw is more recommended for internal elements than using percentages, because using vw gives the width relative to the container in which the element is located.

Thank you! That got everything inside the cyan container, but now the whole cyan container is overflowing the purple container. How do I set the height of the container to be equal to the grid allowance?
